# MySQL - return values in order provided

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I run a lot of `SELECT` statements with `IN` clauses. Sometimes I want to see the output table ordered by the order of values that I used in the `IN` clause, rather than alpha/numerical.

If I ran

```
SELECT id FROM x
WHERE id IN ('1', '3', '2', '0')
```

I would want output `1, 3, 2, 0`, not `0, 1, 2, 3`.

Is there a way to effect this?

Thanks!

Comment: If the ids are numbers, then you shouldn't compare them to string constants.

Answer (score 1):

With the following query you should get what you want:

```
SELECT id FROM x WHERE id IN ('1', '3', '2', '0') ORDER BY FIELD(id, '1', '3', '2', '0')
```

From the MySQL specification about `FIELD()`:

> Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list. Returns 0 if str is not found.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Comment: Like this answer: Order by Field,  I didn't know about it.

Comment: That sounds perfect. Thank you!